# Creating Eq instances for polynomials

Tags: haskell

Representing polynomials in Haskell:

```
newtype Poly a = P [a]
x :: Num a => Poly a
x = P [1]

instance (Num a, Eq a) => Eq (Poly a) where
```

E.g. `P[1,2,3] = 3x^2 + 2x + 1`

I want to say that two polynomials are equal if the lists they have are equal (e.g. `P[1,2,3]` is equal to `P[1,2,3]`). They are also equal if the lists are the same except the last elements are 0's (e.g. `P[1,2,3]` is equal to `P[1,2,3,0,0]`).

However, I don't know the syntax for how to do this.

Comment: What have you done to find out the syntax to do this? There are lots of resources to learn haskell on the Internet (learn you a haskell is a popular one), but stackoverflow is meant to be a place to get help with a particular problem with code, not somewhere to get free tutoring.

Comment: It helps if you can break the problem into pieces. If you could remove all trailing 0's would you know what to do? Would it help to remove just one trailing 0 (if there is one)?

Comment: @bheklir 
I know exactly what to do conceptually and have looked through multiple pages through syntax for hours. Haskell syntax is a problem for me for whatever reason. :/

Comment: @JakeMitchell
I thought I could define it recursively somehow. e.g. P a == P a++[0] = True.

Comment: `removeLeadingZeros (0 : xs) = removeLeadingZeros xs`

Comment: And then `removeLeadingZeros xs = xs` (I'm on my phone. Pardon the concision.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### implementing `Eq`

Just to extend on Jakes answer so you get a complete one:

I like the idea of just removing the leading zeros and with this you soon end up with:

```
newtype Poly a = P [a]

instance (Num a, Eq a) => Eq (Poly a) where
  P xs == P ys =
    removeLeadingZeros (reverse xs) == removeLeadingZeros (reverse ys)

removeLeadingZeros :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [a]
removeLeadingZeros (0 : xs) = removeLeadingZeros xs
removeLeadingZeros xs = xs
```

mind, that you don't really have to `reverse` again to just look for equality (as `xs == ys <=> reverse xs == reverse ys`)

here is a short test session in ghci:

```
λ> let p1 = P[1,2,3,0,0]
λ> let p2 = P[1,2,3]
λ> let p3 = P[1,2,3,0,4]

λ> p1 == p2
True

λ> p1 == p3
False

λ> p2 == p3
False
```

### using *smart* constructors

Another possibility is to not publish the `P` constructor and get the polynoms into a normalized form at construction - this has the advantage that you can just use `deriving Eq`

```
module Poly
       ( Poly, fromList
       ) where

newtype Poly a = P [a]
                 deriving Eq

fromList :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> Poly a
fromList = P . reverse . removeLeadingZeros . reverse
```

#### example

```
λ> let p1 = fromList [1,2,3,0,0]
λ> let p2 = fromList [1,2,3]

λ> p1 == p2
True
```

#### hiding it all

As you already seem to have implemented `Num (Poly a)` you can even remove the `fromList` from the exports - so users have to use arithmetic operators instead to construct polynoms.

You basically just have to export an `x` instead:

```
x :: (Eq a, Num a) => Poly a
x = fromList [0,1]
```

### remarks

Depending on if `P []` is ok for the zero polynom or if you rather have `P [0]` in this case instead you might want to rewrite `removeLeadingZeros` to

```
removeLeadingZeros :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [a]
removeLeadingZeros [0] = [0]
removeLeadingZeros (0 : xs) = removeLeadingZeros xs
removeLeadingZeros xs = xs
```

or something like it

Comment: Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: no problem - the important parts are still all yours ;)

Answer (score 2):

`removeLeadingZeros (0 : xs) = removeLeadingZeros xs
removeLeadingZeros xs = xs`

Reverse the list, remove leading zeros, and then reverse again.

`(reverse . removeLeadingZeros . reverse) [3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

Do the same operation to both polynomials and compare using `==`.

(Untested for now, but I think this is right.)